# How to make a price checker app in android for using in retail outlets?

Tags: android, barcode

I want to develop a price checker app for a retail outlet. There will be a android device with barcode scanner inbuilt. The user can show the barcode with a product before the scanner, then the scanner scans the barcode and show the details of the product, mainly price. I am totally new to this. Is there any SDK s available for this kinds of app? Where can I get started? What all things I need? I have experience in android development. But this kind of app for the first time. Any suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something open-source, [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) has an apache license.

When you can also pay for the SDK, you can find several SDKs using Google.

Comment: Are there pros and cons for open source/paying?